# Event not triggered on appended radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with some radio buttons. This script shows an alert when I change selected radio button

```
$('input[type=radio][name=shipping-h]').change(function () {
    alert("worked");
});
```

I have another script to append a radio button with different value

```
$( "#addressact" ).append('<input id=new-address type=radio name=shipping-h checked>')
```

If I select the new radio button, the alert doesn't work.

Comment: if you are appending a new element you should use event delegation for that

Comment: `$(document).on('change', 'input[name=shipping-h]', function() {`

Comment: can u make fiddle for that?

Comment: thanks pekka, you are solve it.

Comment: glad to help mate here is the documentation for more information http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s7bqa3o9/6/)

```
$(document).on('change', '.qwe', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("worked");
        $("#addressact").append("<input id='new-address' class='qwe'type='radio' name='shipping-h' />");

    }else{
        alert("not checked");
    }

});
```

Added class for reference use only.

If you are appending a new element you should use event delegation for that. This should be used instead `$(document).on('change', 'input[name=shipping-h]', function() {`

Answer (score 1):

you are appending a new element you should use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=shipping-h]', function() {
    alert("worked");
    $( "#addressact" ).append('<input id="new-address"  type="radio" name="shipping-h" checked/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addressact">
  <input type="radio" name="shipping-h"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attaching an event only works for that element as it is at that time. If you append the element afterwards; your previous code (attaching the event) won't magically be executed again.

This means that after appending the input, you need to call the `change()` method (again) to attach the event to the input.

To further clarify; try `alert($('input[type=radio][name=shipping-h]'));` before your current `change()` call; it'll probably say `undefined` as the element doesn't exist at that time

Answer (score 0):

You are appending script, so change event will not bind with jquery. You need to do following step.

```
$( "#addressact" ).append('<input id=new-address onchange="changeevenfun();" type=radio name=shipping-h checked>')

function changeevenfun()
{
    alert("worked");
}
```